# SSRS Indicator by Date Condition

Tags: ssrs-2012

I'm new to SSRS reporting and having some problems with indicators. I am trying to use an indicator to show how long a reservation has been open based on the number of days between the current date and the `RequirementDate` (which is a field in the dataset).

What I want logically is this:

1. If number of days is less than 6 months old, show green
2. If number of days is between 6 months and 8 months, show yellow
3. If number of days is greater than 8 months, show red

Also, I'm not sure where I would enter this kind of formula, as I am doing this from the Indicator Properties window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set these options go into the indicator properties. The easiest way to do this is to right click on the center of the indicator and click `Indicator Properties`. Then click on `Value and States`.

Setting the Green, Yellow, and Red ranges is straight forward for your use case. Just fill in the start and end values with the range of days you want. To set the expression you want for the value click on the fx button next to the value field and use an expression like this one to calculate the days between a date and report runtime.

```
=DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Max(Fields!RequirementDate.Value), Now())
```

[image]